# angular 6 VSTS azure Build ng build configuration=production not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, angular6, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have upgraded to Angular 6 so we had to change the `ng build env=prod` to 
`ng build configuration=production` because angular-cli.json is not being used anymore.

Locally, `ng build configuration=production` works properly and the settings I need in prod were there. But when we trigger the build step/task in azure VSTS, ng build configuration=production does not replace the dev settings to production.

Did anyone encounter this? what did you folks do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try changing your syntax to

`ng run [project]:build:production`

where [project] is replaced with the name of your project as specified in the projects object in angular.json.

For example, if your project is called "my-app", then try

`ng run my-app:build:production`

Second, in angular.json, make sure that my-app > architect > build > configurations > production is defined the way that you expect.

Third, notice that the output of the build will be dist\[project]\production (assuming your "outputPath" is "dist"). You need to ensure that your VSTS build's artifact include these files (for example, by archiving them into a ZIP and then copying them to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)).

Comment: this is great... Thank you so much. Fixed the issue

Comment: Could you take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836391/angular-production-release-does-not-create-my-app-folder-in-dist-azure-devops I am not sure what I am doing wrong.